# Running C++ programs remotely; error loading shared library

Tags: c++, ssh, terminal

I'm a little confused as to what's happening here, when I'm our shared computer I can run our program, but when I ssh in from my house to restart it I get an exception

```
$ ./jsonparser
./jsonparser: error while loading shared libraries: libjansson.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there some other way I should launch the app?

libjansson is installed to /usr/local/lib:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib
libjansson.a  libjansson.la  libjansson.so  libjansson.so.4  libjansson.so.4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe /usr/local/lib is not in your Library pathg ( LD_LIBRARY_PATH I guess )? Or maybe there is a dependency for libjansson.so.4 is not resolved? By using ldd ./jsonparser ldd tries to load all dependent .so-file. Hopefully this will give you some more information about your issue.

Comment: That was it, I guess it doesn't load the setting in my bashrc file when I ssh in..